# Using ILogger in Azure durable function activity?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, cloud, azure-functions

I am using the azure functions for a table insert event trigger, specifically the durable functions, and I'm trying to to produce some logs in my activity function.

The problem is that the activity function does not receive any "ILogger", nor does the orchestrator, thus I don't have any access and cannot produce logs for debug.

The overall flow is:

> HTTP request => Duarble HTTP starter => Durable functions orchestrator => **Durable function activity**.

Is there a way to create a logger instance for some class deriving from ILogger? Or perhaps a way to pass the ILogger instance from the HTTP starter down to the activity function?

Any solution would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the `ILogger` instance is injected in your functions, unless you are using `DI`.

All you need to do is Use the `ILogger` which is injected into your functions.
Example:

```
[FunctionName("Demo")]
public async static Task RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("Starting Orchestration function");
}
```

Incase if you using `Dependency injection` you should just do the below in your startup
`builder.Services.AddLogging();`

#### More Information :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4858

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2720#issuecomment-503627355

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection)

Comment: By default the ILogger isn't injected in the Durable activity function. (It is howerver in the orchestration), so where should the "builder.Services.AddLogging()" be added?

Comment: Inorder to use `builder.Services.AddLogging()` you will need to add `Statup` class and make the function as dependency injected one

Comment: @HariHaran I've implemented DI for durable functions as well but the line above does not seem to work. Can't inject an ILogger via the function or the constructor? Any ideas?

Comment: @BillyRayValentine please raise a question with more error info,i'll check it out.

Comment: Hi @HariHaran, please see question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752340/ilogger-not-injected-in-durable-functions-v2-0

Comment: Does ILogger create any text file or only it writes console in the Azure portal?

Comment: I suggest you also take a look at the `CreateReplaySafeLogger(logger)` extension method. This will ensure that each of your messages are logged only once in the orchestrator lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for some time until I realized that if you're calling your Activity function from your Orchestrator function, using `context.CallActivityAsync()` and are passing `null` as the input (2nd) parameter, then any parameter you add to your Activity function on the 1st position will always be `null`, assuming it is being set through the Orchestrator function. To bypass this, I added a `string dummy` parameter in the 1st position of my Activity function and then added anything else that I needed injected into the function, such as ExecutionContext and the ILogger. Hope this helps!

```
[FunctionName(nameof(RunOrchestrationPipeline))] 
public static void RunOrchestrationPipeline([ActivityTrigger] string dummy, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
{
     log.LogInformation("Orchestration starting...");
     ...
}
```