# ILogger not Injected in Durable Functions v2.0

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

At the moment I'm trying to add an `ILogger` or `ILogger<>` to a Azure Durable Function so as to use logging in Activity Functions.

Logging in the Orchestration Function works fine and is injected in the method itself, but attempts at constructor injection for `ILogger` always results in a Null Exception.

```
builder.Services.AddLogging();
```

The above does not seem to work when added to the Startup file (Bootstrapper) and neither does variations on:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
```

Anyone solved this?

Comment: Are you trying to inject the logger into a different class?

Comment: I have indeed @chris. I think it's a limitation of Activity functions where the logging may need to be passed in using a tuple or otherwise.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#iloggert-and-iloggerfactory), "The host injects ILogger<T> and ILoggerFactory services into constructors. However, by default these new logging filters are filtered out of the function logs. You need to modify the `host.json` file to opt-in to additional filters and categories.

Answer (score 4):

Remove either of these lines from your Startup file:

```
builder.Services.AddLogging();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
```

Then, wherever you are injecting your `ILogger`, add the `type` that your logger is being injected into using `ILogger<T>` i.e:

```
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        return name != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe  logging is added by default so your first suggestion about removing the registration was accurate.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services

Comment: Thanks for your response @chris, this does not work though and is something I'd already tried. Bare in mind, this is Durable Functions and not stateless Azure Functions.

Comment: @BillyRayValentine Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't, in the end the ILogger was passed in the function as opposed to the constructor, which is not ideal but is still the correct logger bootstrapped by the framework.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me adding the type to ILogger<yourClassName> parameter in constructor.